# The cutoff keeps defaulting to 0.05 in Jmol

Tags: computational-chemistry

I am using Jmol for previewing chemical structures. I need the isoSurface value to be 0.008 for 3d printing purposes.But, the cutoff for isosurface keeps defaulting to 0.05.

How should I change it and can anyone also suggest why this keeps happening?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is

```
isoSurface id saSurface radius
```

So you should use

```
isoSurface id saSurface 0.008
```

You can use the optional `id` for giving it a name.

You may also want to see their [reference page](http://jmol.sourceforge.net/docs/surface/)

Edit 1: Have you tried using DX files ?
I am not an expert in using DX to render the required results but here is the reference  :

> DX, as Cube, defines a three-dimensional grid of points in space. At
>   each point is a number (a "scalar value"). This set of point values is
>   then used by Jmol to define an "isosurface" -- the surface separating
>   points having values greater than a given cutoff from those that have
>   a value less than a certain cutoff. A typical application is molecular
>   orbitals. The phase parameter of the isosurface command allows bicolor
>   rendering: one color for "points greater than x" and another color for
>   "points less than -x". Jmol can read DX files and re-export them to
>   much smaller JVXL files.

Quoted from [here](http://wiki.jmol.org/index.php/File_formats/Surfaces)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if its of use but I use the following commands for making jvxl files from cube files under JSmol.  Default cutoff is 0.02.

Isosurface cutoff 0.005 filename_den.cub map  filename_esp.cub

Write isosurface filename.jvxl

Comment: OP wants it for 3D printing, can you use this ff for that purpose?

Comment: So my question I guess is does this fix the issue of it defaulting? because even if I set a cutoff inline in the terminal it still reverts to 0.02